# Scope problems with 'this' keyword

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I am trying to create my own window class which extends `JFrame`.  However, I am having a problem with the action listener for `fullScreenBtn`.  When writing the `ActionListener.actionPerformed` funcion, I am unable to use the `this` keyword as it refers to `new ActionListener`.  How do I refer to the instance of `MyWindow` instead?

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    private static GraphicsEnvironment gEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    private static GraphicsDevice gDev = gEnv.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    private static JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
    private static JButton fullScreenBtn = new JButton("Show Full Screen");
    private static boolean isFullScreen = false;

    public MyWindow() {
        toolbar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        fullScreenBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Toggle full screen window
                this.setUndecorated(!isFullScreen);
                this.setResizable(isFullScreen);
                gDev.setFullScreenWindow(this);

                isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;

                if (isFullScreen) {
                    fullScreenBtn.setText("Show Windowed");
                } else {
                    fullScreenBtn.setText("Show Full Screen");
                }
            }
        });

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                this.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In inner classes you will need to prepend your use of `this` with the class name of the outer class if you need to obtain a reference to the outer class: For example, use

```
MyWindow.this.setUndecorated(...)` 
//  etc...
```

As an aside, you really don't want to extend JFrame here, and in most situations.

Also, the ancestor Window that holds the JButton can be obtained in other ways such as via `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(theButton)`. i.e.,

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JButton) {
              JButton button = (button) source;
              Window ancestorWin = SwingUtilities.getAncestorWindow(button);
              ancestorWin.setUndecorated(!isFullScreen);
              ancestorWin.setResizable(isFullScreen);
              // etc...
```

Or if you know most definitely that the ancestor window is a JFrame:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JButton) {
              JButton button = (button) source;

              JFrame ancestorWin = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getAncestorWindow(button);
              ancestorWin.setUndecorated(!isFullScreen);
              ancestorWin.setResizable(isFullScreen);
              // etc...
```

Comment: Just vote to close this question, which is an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I knew there had to be a simple way of doing it.  How would you recommend creating this kind of class without extending JFrame?

Comment: @MattBall: yes, you are right. If you find the dup, I will add my vote. Edit: vote added.

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax of accessing the enclosing-class's instance from an inner-class or an anonymous-class:

```
OuterClass.this.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using an `anonymous class`, `this` will refer to that class, in this case the `ActionListener`. Because your `ActionListener` doesn't have methods such as `setUndecorated`, this will give you a compile error.

What you want to do is use `MyWindow.this`, followed by any method of `MyWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to access `this` by specifying the outer class too, in your case it has to be something like follows:

```
MyWindow.this
```